# Upload image using AJAX in Joomla 3.0 MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am trying to upload a image using AJAX jquery in a Joomla MVC framework.

Below is the default.php which adds the below javascript script code

```
$('#icon-submit').on('click',(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_jsmdownload&task=imageUpload",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
    }
  });
}));
```

Below is the HTML code which contains a simple file box and a button

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="POST" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="and_36x36" name="and_36x36">
  <input id='icon-submit' type='button' value='Next ->' />
</form>
```

Below is the PHP code in controller.php for the imageUpload task.

```
function imageUpload(){
  JFactory::getDocument()->setMimeEncoding( 'application/json' );
  print_r($_FILES);
  JFactory::getApplication()->close();
}
```

Once I select the file and click on the button the ajax function called and the PHP function also called but the form data is not available inside.

The print_r command always prints an empty array.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I want to get the selected file and upload them into the server and return back to the browser.

I referred multiple posts and cant able to find an answer.  Can someone please advice.

**UPDATE 1**

If I set a independent PHP file as URL then it works.  For example

```
url: "http://localhost/test/indextest.php",
```

But If I set the Joomla component path with controller it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this component `com_jsmdownload` require the user to be logged in to upload images? or will it let anyone?

Comment: Why not use the built in package for uploading? Uploading images is dangerous, you need to build in authentication checks, authorization checks, extensive checks of the name and whether the image itself contain malicious code. I'd read the OWASP site carefully before rolling your own.

Comment: @cppl - yes this component is only for registered users. Is there a built in package available for Joomla to upload images?

Comment: I managed to make it work. Refer the link http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5342/upload-image-using-ajax-in-joomla-3-0-mvc

Comment: The field type media will give you an uploader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the form to the FormData object, what you have is the button.
in the button click event handler `this` refers to the button not the form.
Select the form and pass it to the FormData constructor

```
new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]),
```

Comment: tried this now and still the results are same. I couldn't get the form data inside the PHP.